# android path priority jobqueue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This question pertains to the Path - Priority job queue for android.
My problem is that threads started by the jobqueue are not killed after completion of the job.
I currently have the following configuration in the application class.

```
                   Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(this)
          .customLogger(new CustomLogger() {
       private static final String TAG = "SS.JOBS";

            @Override
            public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void d(String text, Object... args) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format(text, args));
            }

            @Override
            public void e(Throwable t, String text, Object... args) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.format(text, args), t);
            }

            @Override
            public void e(String text, Object... args) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.format(text, args));
            }
        }).minConsumerCount(0)// always keep at least one consumer alive
        .maxConsumerCount(3)// up to 3 consumers at a time
        .loadFactor(3)// 3 jobs per consumer
        .consumerKeepAlive(120)// wait 2 minute
        .build();
jobManager = new JobManager(this, configuration);
```

Even after my job completes , I keep getting "didnt allow me to die" forever.
I have kept the phone connected to logcat and even after 2 days, i get this line, in logcat. 
Particularly, the line appears exactly every two minutes.
I need help on how to configure this to not happen. It means that the thread is running despite the job being completed, and this is a waste of resources.

While running my jobs I do not need 'requireNetwork' or persist.
So I do not pass in any arguments for those.
My constructor looks like:

```
                   super(new Params(SsConstants.LOAD_NEWS_FEED_FROM_TABLE_JOB_PRIORITY));
```

The logcat message is -

```
 Thread 1206: Load factor check, true = (0 < 1)||(0*3 < 0 + 0) consumer thread : true
  didn't allow me to die re-running thread 1206
  rerunning consumer 1206
```

Regards
Bhargav

Answer (score 0):

Little bit strange. try to not set minConsumerCount in your configuration. You should not set that if you minConsumerCount = 0